# Avoid parsing huge XML element with lxml

Tags: xml, python-3.x, lxml

I am parsing XML files which have PDF files embedded inside certain elements.

I already switched to `iterparse()` to try and clear those elements, e.g.:

```
for event, element in iterparse(f):
    if element.xpath('local-name()') == 'AttachedFile':
        element.clear()
```

But it will not work.

There can be multiple `AttachedFile` elements per document, and I have noticed the code above does not even reach the second element, i.e. it raises `lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: xmlSAX2Characters: huge text node` immediately.

Is there any way I can tell the parser to not even try to parse such elements? Or any other workaround?

Comment: Please show XML and desired result.

Comment: I cannot skip the problematic element but I could get the parsing complete successfully by passing `huge_tree=True` to the `iterparse()` function. **huge_tree**: *disable security restrictions and support very deep trees
and very long text content* (see http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.iterparse-class.html)

Comment: Not sure if you are responding to me but please refer to previous comment.